# Склеивание коллекций из iterables по ключу. Python

Tags: python-3.8

Моя задача состоит в склеивание коллекций из 'iterables'.
Знаю что мне может помочь функция chain из itertools, но нужно еще склеивать по ключу key и порядку меньше, а в случае равенства данных упорядочить по следованию коллекций. Я не понимаю как именно можно соединять коллекции по какому-то ключу, например по дате-времени.

Comment: Прийдется развернуть последовательности в list, потому как не ясно в какой последовательности приходят данные. Сопоставления могут быть с разных концов

Comment: Данных может быть очень много, возможно это будет неэффективно по памяти

Comment: Ну не сделаешь join в один проход

Comment: Ещё проход на сортировку

Comment: Не понимаю как эффективно отсортировать по памяти много больших коллекций

Comment: Загони колекции в пандас и сортируй с диска